# .documentID not returning correct information

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

## Issue

I've created a dropdown menu and when users click on certain items, it gives them the option to delete it. However, when I try to get the document ID of the selected item it instead returns the value of what I selected.

## Example

When I click on Email in my dropdown menu it prints "Email" which is a field value 'Name' : 'Email' from document DjgTDgbW4CkHMURnz32T. However, when I try and print the document ID of "Email", the field value just gets printed instead.

## Tested so far

So far I know that userDocSTRING & userCatSTRING are correct and when I print _selectedCATEGORY, the correct value is also printed. But for some reason when I put .documentID at the end, "Email" gets printed instead. Flutter doctor returns no errors and not error logs get printed either.

## Code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firepass/Assets/Colors/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firepass/Firebase/login_auth.dart';

// Instantiate stream for listening to category changes
// Used in all dropdown menus
class CategorySettings extends StatefulWidget {
  CategorySettingsSTATE createState() => CategorySettingsSTATE();
}

class CategorySettingsSTATE extends State<CategorySettings> {
  var selectedCATEGORY;
  bool _deleteABLE = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document(userDocSTRING.toString())
            .collection(userCatSTRING.toString())
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            List<DropdownMenuItem> catItems = [];
            for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
              DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.documents[i];
              catItems.add(DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(snap.data['Name']),
                value: "${snap.data['Name']}",
              ));
            }

            return Column(children: <Widget>[
              DropdownButton(
                  items: catItems.toList(),
                  onChanged: (categoryVALUE) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedCATEGORY = categoryVALUE;
                      DeleteButtonSTATE().delete = categoryVALUE;
                      if (categoryVALUE == 'All') {
                        _deleteABLE = false;
                        print(
                            'Category can be deleted ==== ${_deleteABLE.toString()}');
                      } else
                        _deleteABLE = true;
                      print(categoryVALUE.toString());
                    });
                  },
                  value: selectedCATEGORY,
                  isExpanded: false),
              _deleteABLE == true
                  ? DeleteBUTTON()
                  : Container(height: 0.0, width: 0.0)
            ]);
          }
        });
  }
}

class DeleteBUTTON extends StatefulWidget {
  DeleteButtonSTATE createState() => DeleteButtonSTATE();
}

class DeleteButtonSTATE extends State<DeleteBUTTON> {
  var delete;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
          onPressed: () {
            print(delete.toString());
          }),
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('Category ${CategorySettingsSTATE().toString()} Deleted');

            Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(userDocSTRING.toString())
                .collection(userCatSTRING.toString())
                .document(CategorySettingsSTATE().selectedCATEGORY.toString())
                .delete();
          },
          child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80),
              elevation: 0,
              color: accentRedColor,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.delete_forever,
                          color: whiteCOLOR,
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10)),
                        Text('Delete',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: whiteTextCOLOR, fontSize: 12))
                      ]))))
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, try this:

```
var query = Firestore.instance
                     .collection('users')
                     .document(userDocSTRING.toString())
                     .collection(userCatSTRING.toString())
                     .where('Name', isEqualTo: _selectedCATEGORY);

var category = (await query.getDocuments()).documents[0].documentID;
```

But because of how complicated this is, I would consider using the categories' names as their IDs. So instead of a random ID, you'll have "Email" as the ID of the category "Email".

Comment: If you click on this link, you'll see the structure I currently have in my app  - https://imgur.com/a/nTLfnIK.The collection that "Email" is stored in actually has a randomly generated ID. The userCatSTRING is actually referring to a collection in the user's areas (document) where all the categories are kept. That's my bad for not showing all my variables - but it would be far to long to show the entire code base.

Comment: What are the values of your DropDownButton?

Comment: The app is a password manager and the idea is that when the user creates a new password, they can select the categories for which that password belongs to. But the user can set their own categories.

Comment: It wasn't accepting the ```await``` but I've update my original post with my entire code for this page. No matter what I do, I cannot seem to use ```selectedCategory``` anywhere other than in the DropdownButton which makes me think that I am doing something horribly wrong!

Comment: What do you mean by “it wasn’t accepting the await”? Did you add the `async` keyword to the function containing await?

Comment: I've wrapped it in an Async function now but getting this error message https://imgur.com/a/KVMmSin I've also tried using the field name as the document ID like you suggested but this still doesn't work.

Comment: I can’t see very well on your first picture but it appears that the property ‘Name’ starts by a capital letter? Change the query accordingly.

Comment: Afternoon Jalil, your previous comment of "why are you using a dropdown button" got me thinking and it was causing too much hassle. I've spent a hour and managed to create a whole new system whereby the categories get displayed in side scrolling list view. This worked like a charm and looks a lot more finished!